# material not appearing transparent. what is my mistake?

Tags: shaders

[image: now looking like this]
**now looking like this**

[image: my settings]
**my settings**

[image: supposted to look like this]
**supposted to look like this**

[image: png file]

Comment: Can you post a link to the "chiffon.png" texture itself? If the .PNG uses alpha transparency to achieve its effect, you may need to use the "Alpha" output socket instead of the "Color" output socket on the Texture Node for some of the transparency blending, but this would just be a guess without seeing the .PNG file.

Comment: I just added png

Comment: I just tested it out, and your node setup works perfectly on my end. I get a sheer, blue chiffon when I render, which is transparent between the "threads". I did notice that your Viewport Shading is set to "Material" instead of "Render", and I don't think the transparency will show up in "Material" view. Does this issue still occur when you render?